# findDOMNode of mounted component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, validation, input, components, reactjs

I have two JS files included in page as utility.js and utility1.js 
 Code for utility.js

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        Hello, <input type="text" ref="mytestinput" placeholder="Your name here" />!<br />
        It is {this.props.date.toTimeString()}
      </p>
    );
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  React.render(
    <HelloWorld date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
}, 1000);
```

Code for utility1.js

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API.
    React.findDOMNode(HelloWorld.refs.mytestinput).focus();
  },
  render: function() {
    // The ref attribute adds a reference to the component to
    // this.refs when the component is mounted.
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref="myTextInput" />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container1')
);
```

The problem here is I want focus on input of HelloWorld Component of utility.js from utility1.js. I saw their is one method as findDOMNode for mounted components. But this code is not working for me. Can Somebody try this JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vivek07mishra/pzfwvjdf/10/) and let me know possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the global event system in order to allow both components [communicate with each other](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) if they are not in parent-child relationship. Here is more information about [global event system](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/Eaa0-SGwAjM)

Here is the solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzfwvjdf/11/)

```
var CustomEvents = (function() {
  var _map = {};

  return {
    subscribe: function(name, cb) {
      _map[name] || (_map[name] = []);
      _map[name].push(cb);
    },

    notify: function(name, data) {
      if (!_map[name]) {
        return;
      }

      // if you want canceling or anything else, add it in to this cb loop
      _map[name].forEach(function(cb) {
        cb(data);
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Can you explain how this subscribe and notify work. what is cb(data) in notify method.

Comment: this is just a basic example. You should develop your own event system.

Comment: Subscribe(name, cb) will register events (name) and event handlers (cb). And notify is used to execute those events and also to pass data from one component to other component. In this case, you use subscribe to create an event listener (foo) in HelloWorld component. Whenever you call notify(foo,'focus'), it will execute the foo function. cb(data) here is used  to pass data from remote component to event handlers of an other component. Honestly, my example is not good but I hope it help you grasp the idea of global event system.

Answer (score 1):

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    React.findDomNode(this.refs.mytestinput).focus()
  },
  ...
});
```

or if your React.js is up-to-date, use this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.refs.mytestinput.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refs are local to the component they are defined on, so `HelloWorld.refs.mytestinput` is not valid. Furthermore, since `MyComponent` and `HelloWorld` are part of two different React applications (created by two different calls to `React.render`), there's no built-in way to access the refs in `HelloWorld` from `MyComponent`. You would need to set some kind of global reference to the component, use message passing from one app to the other, emit events of some kind indicating the input should be focused, or use some other method of "global" communication.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
this.refs.myTextInput
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0cjqLu2/